# Robot Framework IDE (RIDE) Execution profiles not showing up

Tags: python, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I have installed Robot Framework for multiple machines. There are python2 and python3 and packeges for them on both. The process of the installation was the same. On machine `A` there are more Execution Profile (`jybot`, `pybot`, `robot`, `robot 3.1`) while on the other (`B`) there are only `jybot` and `pybot` if I start RIDE with python2 and `jybot` and `robot` if python3.

What is the difference, or how can I add more Execution Profiles for RIDE?

- Python 2.7.11

  - robotframework==3.0
  - robotframework-ride==1.5.2.1
- Python 3.7.4

  - robotframework==3.1.2
  - robotframework-ride==1.7.3.1

*There is no robotframework related difference in PATH*

**EDIT**

Machine `A`

python2 robotframework related packages

```
robotframework==3.0
robotframework-androidlibrary==0.2.0
robotframework-appiumlibrary==1.5.0.6
robotframework-archivelibrary==0.4.0
robotframework-databaselibrary==0.8.1
robotframework-excellibrary==0.0.2
robotframework-httplibrary==0.4.2
robotframework-pabot==0.31
robotframework-ride==1.5.2.1
robotframework-selenium2library==1.7.4
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==2.9.2
robotframework-sshlibrary==3.4.0
robotremoteserver==1.0.1
```

python3 robotframework related packages

```
robotframework==3.1.2
robotframework-httplibrary3==0.6.0
robotframework-pabot==0.99
robotframework-ride==1.7.3.1
robotframework-selenium2library==3.0.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==4.1.0
robotframework-sshlibrary==3.4.0
robotframeworklexer==1.1
robotremoteserver==1.1
```

Machine `B`

python2 robotframework related packages

```
robotframework==3.0
robotframework-androidlibrary==0.2.0
robotframework-archivelibrary==0.4.0
robotframework-databaselibrary==0.8.1
robotframework-extendedselenium2library==0.9.1
robotframework-imagehorizonlibrary==0.1
robotframework-pabot==0.31
robotframework-python3==2.9
robotframework-ride==1.5.2.1
robotframework-selenium2library==1.7.4
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==2.9.1
robotframework-sshlibrary==2.1.3
robotframeworklexer==1.1
robotremoteserver==1.0.1
```

python3 robotframework related packages

```
robotframework==3.1.2
robotframework-httplibrary3==0.6.0
robotframework-pabot==0.99
robotframework-ride==1.7.3.1
robotframework-selenium2library==3.0.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==4.1.0
robotframework-sshlibrary==3.4.0
robotframeworklexer==1.1
robotremoteserver==1.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found it.

In `C:\<username>\AppData\Roaming\RobotFramework\ride` folder there is a **settings.cfg** file.

In this file there was a `runprofiles = [('jybot', 'jybot.bat')]` row.

I've changed it to `runprofiles = [('jybot', 'jybot.bat'), ('pybot', 'pybot.bat'), ('robot 3.1', 'robot')]` and now I can modify the Execution Profile in RIDE as I want.

But I don't really understand and can't explain why and when became the two `setting.cfg` files different.

Answer (score 0):

The detection of robot executable is not dependent on the version of RIDE, but on the installed version in Python. But this may result in different robot being executed when running tests. When the test is executed, it should use the robot as it would if launched from command line.

Like was mentioned by Bence Kaulics, `pybot`was renamed to `robot` from certain version. And in version 3.1.x, robot was changed to an executable instead of a .bat file (in Windows). That was the reason to have both `robot` and `robot 3.1`. So, in Windows, when selecting `robot`you may be executing a `robot.cmd` script. The same is valid for `pybot.bat` with profile `pybot`.

**EDIT**:
You can compare the `settings.cfg` file from the two machines. See it at `~/.robotframework/ride/settings.cfg` (or `%APPDATA%\robotframework\ride\settings.cfg` ), on the [Plugins][[Test Runner]] section, the `run_profiles` property is defined there.

Comment: OK, but this still doesn't answer my question. How can I force RIDE to show also robot any pybot as execution profile, when RIDE started with python3. On machine `A` I have 4 execution profiles, on `B` only 2, and the second depends on python version. Also the python folders are the same on the machines.